# How can I pass the output of the cat/ls -l command to an argument in unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cat

I've got an assignment that says, "If you enter 'type', it should respond with the prompt 'Enter file name:' and then have you type something in. If you enter a valid file name, it should respond with a listing of the file, and exit."

Here's the code I have so far:

```
type)
 echo "Enter file name:"
read var
if [ -f "${var}" ]; 
then
     ???
exit
fi
;;
```

I'm trying to figure out what to enter where I put the ??? to display the contents of whatever file is entered the same way the cat command would. I  thought it'd be something simple like echo $CAT but that hasn't worked.

And then I'm trying to do the same thing but with a directory, outputting the ls -l listing of it rather than file contents.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: how bout: cat "${var}"

Comment: Or just `cat "$var"`; the curly braces don't do anything useful in this context (whereas without the quotes, names with spaces / glob characters / etc wouldn't work).

Comment: Lacks specifications: if you enter value other than "type" what are the expected results? If you do not enter a valid filename ...? If you enter a valid filename that exists in a directory which the user does not have permissions to access ...? What do you mean by "valid file name" (i.e. excl. "special files")?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
if [ -f "$var" ] 
then
     cat "$var"
elif [ -d "$var" ]
then
    ls -l "$var"
fi
```

Comment: What will happen when someone just hits ENTER on the question? Or `filename with spaces` ? Please quote `$var`.